# Online Accounts

Tags: google, online-accounts

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell Inspiron 15 3585 laptop. I'm trying to add my Google account in Online accounts. I enter my email address and password, but nothing happens. The blue bar just runs across the top of the password box waiting for a response, but it never comes. I do have 2FA, but it never gets to the point of asking for the code.

Answer (score 8):

When you enter your correct password it will start loading forever, at that moment Right-click on the window and hit reload.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem. After reloading I was asked to verify using 2FA.

Comment: Wow. I did not expect it to work that easily !  Now I even get access to my Google Drive. Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me as well, thank you!